# In the US, how can a federal law be prevented from being made?

Tags: united-states, legislation

I often hear about measures that both major parties employ to prevent laws they do not like from passing, but in asking this question I would also like to know what a third party could potentially do to that end. Both in case of specific laws and all legislation in general.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question is just asking how a bill is turned into law?

Comment: **Jury Nullification** is always an option.

Comment: @user1873 - Jury Nullification doesn't prevent the law from being made. Merely from being applied in one, specific, court case.

Comment: This question needs some clarification. Are you talking about the process prior to a bill being passed as a law? Or are you talking about repealing existing laws? (in either case, however, the process would be the same for everyone--regardless of the political party they belong to)

Comment: I am talking about the process prior to abill being passed as a law.

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming you mean: in Congress, before a bill is passed, how can a party prevent a bill from passing:

1. Obviously, vote against it, on the full floor of either House
2. Kill(vote against) or pigeonhole(take no action on) it in the Committee
3. In the House of Representatives, in the Rules Committee, pass a restricting rule or schedule for a non-in-session date

Out of Congress, before a bill becomes law, obviously you have the Presidential Veto, which in the vast majority of cases kills the bill.